# React Testing Library merged with @testing-library/react-hooks, wrapper inconsistent in renderHook

Tags: react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

With **@testing-library/react-hooks** I used to pass mocked store through `initialProps` just as mentioned in [Advanced Hooks](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks) docs. Let's assume I have a code:

```js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const initialState = {}
const customStore = configureMockStore(initialState)

// this wrapper is nicely reusable across all tests
const wrapper = ({ children, store = customStore }) =>
  <Provider store={ store }>
    {children}
  </Provider>

const useCustomHook = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ACTION' })
  }, [])
}

test('should get dispatched action', () => {
  renderHook(useCustomHook, {
    wrapper: wrapper,
    initialProps: {
      store: customStore
    }
  })

  expect(customStore.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: 'ACTION }])
})
```

If I run this code with RTL before update (version 10.4.5) and @testing-library/react-hooks everything works as expected. But after these packages have merged, `wrapper` property in `renderHooks` function doesn't accept any other properties except `children`.

First iteration lead me to this solution:

```js
renderHook(useCustomHook, {
  wrapper: ({ children }) => (
   <Provider store={ customStore }>{children}</Provider>
  )
})
```

...that's not as good in reusability as my previous wrapper. Is there any good solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue, want to renderHook, but hook uses state that it has not been provided without being wrapped, will want to pass multiple providers so want a helper, which i can overwrite state in the store with.

Comment: @Jeremy yep. I'll make an answer rn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

```js
const customWrapper = (store) => ({ children }) =>
  // this function is mentioned in question
  wrapper({
    children,
    store
  })
  
test('Some test #1', () => {
  const mockedState = {}
  const mockedStore = configureMockStore(mockedState)

  const { result } = renderHook(() => useCustomHook(), {
    wrapper: customWrapper(mockedStore)
  })
})
```